# "Teclado Virtual" - Java Android

Tags: java, android

Boas, estou a precisar de uma pequena ajuda. 
Estava a pensar criar uma espécie de teclado com apenas alguns botões para a minha aplicação Android mas não estou a conseguir o que pretendo.
[image: Teclado]

Eu pretendia criar este teclado e digitar os carateres na barra branca em cima, que é um EditText já criado. O problema que estou a ter é que sempre que eu pressiono um botão, só aparece o seu valor na barra, e não a sequência como normalmente acontece com qualquer teclado.
Eu acho que é por causa do "setText"  que existe no método de cada botão mas não sei nenhuma maneira de solucionar. 
Obrigado se me puderem ajudar

Comment: pelo que pude entender voce quer pressionar o botão e enquanto ele tiver pressionado o respectivo caracter vai se repetindo na caixa de edição, eh isso?

Comment: Eu queria mesmo tornar esses botões num teclado normal

Comment: cara, seria o mesmo se voce montasse um layout normal e implementasse os eventos de teclado normais do device via código, fácil de resolver, algo tipo, vamos supor, o "(": no layout um button e no código o seu respectivo onclick, onlongclick e por ai vai. É isso? ou voce quer usar o próprio teclado do aparelho? ainda to boiando...

Comment: Armando, eu queria simplesmente criar um teclado com aqueles botões.
Já encontrei solução na resposta do Leonardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método [append()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)) do EditText. Ele vai acrescentar o que você passar por parâmetro ao que já está presente no EditText.

```
editText.append(")");
editText.append("1");
```

Comment: Obrigado Leonardo, mas já agora, uma pequena dúvida, se eu criar o botão de apagar como faço?

Comment: O segundo trecho de código [desta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22316621/4350835) remove o último caractere de um `EditText`.

Comment: Muito Obrigado :) Ta resolvido